# Multithreading and Parallellism definitions

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I've started studying multithreading in C++ and I'm trying to understand how it works, but on the internet I can't find a clear explanation.
I have wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 
using namespace std; 


void thread_one() 
{ 
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << " - " << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    }
} 

void thread_two() 
{ 
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << " * " << std::flush;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1000ms);
    }
} 

int main() 
{ 

    thread th1(thread_one); 
    thread th2(thread_two); 

    th1.join(); 
    th2.join();
}
```

which will give me something like : * - - - * * * - * - , therefore they are clearly running at the same time.

Now from the definitions that I found on the internet I can't get if this program is running in parallel or if it's a multithreading application, I can't get the difference.
From what I've understood :
with multithreading the computer can run (if available) on more than one core, therefore doing more than one tasks at the same time (Concurrently ?)
parallellism is when a single core is doing 2 different things concurrently.

But still I can't get if doing a code like this is multithreading or parallellism and if my understanding are correct or not.

Can someone please explain to me the exact difference?
thanks in advance

Comment: Your code creates 2 threads.  If your computer has 2 or more cores then the code could run in parallel (for a time-slice), this depends on the OS scheduler and whatever else the computer needs to do.  If your computer only has 1 core, then each thread will be scheduled for a time-slice on the single core, again this depends on the OS scheduler and other external work.

Comment: @Franceso2 *>parallellism is when a single core is doing 2 different things concurrently* "This is "instruction-level parallelism", a special case of generic term "parallelism".

Answer (score 3):

"Parallelism" is something entirely different from "concurrency".

You are mixing up "multi processing" with "multi threading" on the OS side (this introduces concurrency), and "multi CPU" vs "multi-core" vs "SMT" on the hardware end (this introduces parallelism).

"Parallelism" says "you are actually doing something in parallel". You actually need 2 or more instances of any resource to achieve this.

"Concurrency" says primarily "you are going to have conflicts on shared resources".

As it happens, you do have 2 threads which are running concurrently, and both are sharing your terminal as a common resource.

As both of them hang mostly in sleeps, they didn't actually ran in "parallel" though. Your operating systems scheduler could have very well scheduled them both to the same CPU core, sequentially, and you wouldn't have noticed.

Scheduling is the keyword here, as soon as you try to run more tasks concurrently than you have resources for, the scheduler starts arbitration of the resources. If you were to do this with more threads than you CPU cores for, and you didn't used sleeps either, you would *still* see the outputs from *all* threads interleaved, as the scheduler will use eviction as a strategy for fair scheduling, even in the absence of an voluntary yield.

Comment: Ok therefore my application is running concurrently since it's using 2 threads to share the same resource ( the terminal )
if i were to do 2 different things like : doing some calculation on one varaible and other calculation on another varialbe, which have nothing to share between each other, then the application would be multithreading and not parallel anymore? Thanks!

Comment: @Franceso2 That's not actually a correct understanding. It is irrelevant whether two threads are doing the same thing or different things - that is not the deciding factor. This answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59624515/2836621

Comment: ok thanks for the link it was really usefull! Can't upvote you, I dont have enough reputation..

Answer (score 1):

**Computer science-y definition of *concurrency*:** Two program operations are *concurrent* with each other if the program does not guarantee that they always will be performed one after another, and always in the same order.

**Informal definition that often amounts to the same thing:** Two activities/function-calls/processes/threads/etc. are *concurrent* with each other if there is any moment in time when both of them have been started, but neither one of them has finished.

**Parallel computation:** happens when a single computation is able to exploit multiple instances of some kind of computing hardware. Besides using multiple processes or threads on a single [symmetric multiprocessing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_multiprocessing) computer, or on a cluster of computers; there are/have been other, more esoteric computer architectures meant for parallel computing such as; [pipelined graphics processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline), [vector processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor), [systolic array processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systolic_array), and [reconfigurable processors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconfigurable_computing).