# Parallelizing independent creation of Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a general question about parallelizing Dataframe operations.

Let's say I have an operation like this in mind (pseudo-Code, `df`, `df1` and `df2` are DataFrames)

```
df1 = pandas_operations(df, arg1, arg2)
df2 = pandas_operations(df, arg3, arg4)
result = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

where `pandas_operations` is some function that makes heavy use of the pandas API to crunch numbers.

In what situations would creating `df1` and `df2` in parallel (e.g. with `multiprocessing`) make sense in order to speed up the program?

I am mainly asking this question because `pandas` delegates a lot of computation heavy tasks to `numpy`, which (as I understand) already makes use of multiple cores when calling code written in C. If this were true, then I could parallelize the creation of `df1` and `df2` with `multiprocessing`, but the creation of each Dataframe would likely be slower than in the sequential program.

Comment: What also matters is how are you creating a dataframe. Is `df` meant to be a data-provider dataset from which some data is taken and transformed to further build a new dataframe, within a separate process ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes, we can assume that. Let's say `df` comes from a database query or from a file.

Comment: a pseudo-code of your current `pandas_operations` would be desirable to post

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yeah I know, I'm truly sorry but I cannot provide specifics because the code would come from other developers. I was hoping the question as is would be enough information for a general answer like "no, numpy already parallelizes all the computation heavy tasks, manually parallelizing the code is futile" or "depending on what's going on in `pandas_operations`, you can expect multiprocessing to speed up the program significantly".

Comment: If `pandas_operations` is undefined and the operations are truly independent, then it might make sense to parallelize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not want to make belive like i an an expert in that domain, but i think there is a significant difference between what numpy does, which is called [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) for **Single Instruction, Multiple Data**, and that allows to vectorize operations for speed. This happends at the level of the architecture of the CPU. Multiprocessing is having several CPUs that can each do SIMD, from my understanding, at least.

I think reading this post, from a more knowledgeable person, may help : [Difference between SIMD and Multi-threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59623054/difference-between-simd-and-multi-threading). It also speaks about differences between SIMD and multi-processing.

So to answer the initial question, it will likely be faster (but this is very high level and would need to be quantified, i bet it would depend on the size and number of dataframes. Instanciating new pools for a few elements that are fast to process may be counter productive) to create df1 and df2 in parallel, but it will be more RAM intensive as df data has to be duplidated and passed to the two independant processes.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I'm aware that the question is too general for a more specific answer.